# Joomla website showing white screen on android default browser after page refresh

Tags: android, html, css, joomla3.0

I design new website using Joomla but this time I see something strange!

On any android device (by default browser (chrome)), it will show white screen if I refresh any pages of website.

please note it will happen only at "page refresh" events. I mean when you directly open the site with using address-bar and if you open links inside the website, it will show the page correctly, but if you refresh current page (with using "refresh button") you will see a "white screen" without any content.

I am sure that content is loaded correctly, because if you change the rotation of your tablet (or mobile) or if you tap white page and try to scroll down, website will appear!

seems there is several type of report for this problem:
https://superuser.com/questions/440416/chrome-displays-a-page-for-split-second-then-it-goes-blank

but I could not solve the problem with those solutions.

do you know any way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

in Joomla by default jQuery is loaded. in Joomla 3.6.2 (that I am using), it's loading `jQuery v1.12.4` by default that is stored in this directory:
 `/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js`

I just try to replace it by latest version, it solve problem but it create another one! in the console log I got a message that I can't use jQuery V3 because of bootstrap. then I downgrade to `jQuery v2.2.4` (the latest version before version 3) and Hoooraaaaaaaaa, it's working now without any problem.

hope it help someone else

thanks